# Constrained Optimization in R (find parameter)

Tags: r, optimization, constraints

I have a predator(Humans)–prey(fish) model under the following system of equations:

dx/dt = a*x−g*x^2 − b*x*y
dy/dt = −c*y + d*x*y

I would like to find the minimum value for "b"  (with R code), at which the human population dies out (y < 1) and state this value. I am meant to search "b" within [0.2,0.4]

I have done the below but i am not sure if i am establishing correctly the constraint y=[0,1] or even if i should be using the second equation (the one without b)

```
Objb<-function(b,a,x,g,y) (a*x-g*x^2-b*x*y)

    optimize(Objb, a=5,x=20,g=0.0001,y=0, lower=0.2, upper=0.4,maximum = FALSE)
    optimize(Objb, a=5,x=20,g=0.0001,y=0.5, lower=0.2, upper=0.4,maximum = FALSE)
    optimize(Objb, a=5,x=20,g=0.0001,y=1, lower=0.2, upper=0.4,maximum = FALSE)
```

and got

```
optimize(Objb, a=5,x=20,g=0.0001,y=0, lower=0.2, upper=0.4,maximum = FALSE)
# $minimum
# [1] 0.3999501
# 
# $objective
# [1] 99.96
# 
optimize(Objb, a=5,x=20,g=0.0001,y=0.5, lower=0.2, upper=0.4,maximum = FALSE)
# $minimum
# [1] 0.3999501
# 
# $objective
# [1] 95.9605

optimize(Objb, a=5,x=20,g=0.0001,y=1, lower=0.2, upper=0.4,maximum = FALSE)
# $minimum
# [1] 0.3999501
# 
# $objective
# [1] 91.961
```

Comment: See https://strimas.com/post/lotka-volterra/ and https://rpubs.com/Jeet1994/Prey-predator-model  and https://www.r-bloggers.com/2010/03/lotka-volterra-model%C2%A0%C2%A0intro/

Comment: It look like you are minimizing your derivative rather than it’s integral.

Comment: @G. Grothendieck, Thanks for the links. They´re really good. I am able to reproduce the model itself but unable to set up what it seems an optimization question.

Comment: @IRTFM, correct, as part of the model.

Comment: Do this: `plot(x=seq(.2, .4, length=100), Objb(b=seq(.2, .4, length=100),x=20,a=5,g=0.0001, y=0))`

Comment: @IRTFM, Thanks! I think that will work in a way. Appreciated.

Comment: I was offering that as a way to "visualize" the fact that there would be no meaningful minimum, i.e., that optimization of that sort made no sense.

Comment: @IRTFM, I did y<0 for the same plot. plot(x=seq(.2, .4, length=100), Objb(b=seq(.2, .4, length=100),x=20,a=5,g=0.0001, y<0)). b=0.4 seems to minimize the function if y not 0, i think. Or am i misreading it?

Comment: I don't understand how `y<0` can be a parameter for Objb. And the objective value is pretty arbitrary if you make y negative. What does it mean when you are minimizing b at a value of y that makes no sense?

Comment: @IRTFM, Ok. Need to think about it again. Thanks.